# jquery + PHP, GWT or jquery + JSP

Tags: php, jquery, gwt, tomcat, jboss

I've got an architecture question that I was hoping some programmers smarter than me could help me with.

I work at a software company and I build custom software that interacts with our primary software product.  Our software runs on Tomcat in a JBOSS server.

Typically when I write software I write it in PHP + jQuery.  It's easy to stand up a quick project and straightforward to maintain.  Whenever I use this software I have to set up an entirely separate environment on the server I am deploying with PHP on IIS7.  It seems like a waste when all of our servers are already running Tomcat and JBOSS.

I really like the flexibility and quick development time of PHP + jQuery, but I love the fact that I could "drop in" and deploy a .war file if I was using GWT or writing custom .jsp files that contain HTML + jQuery.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a better approach of using Tomcat or JBOSS with the flexibility of writing straight jQuery + PHP?

Comment: PHP is server side and jQuery is client side. How would the combination matter?

Comment: Yes, PHP on the server side and jQuery on the client side OR GWT: writing java, translated to javascript OR using JSP on the server side and jQuery on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use GWT or if you build .war files, you still have to go through a build step and, if you're trying to avoid that while developing the code, then you can simply create JSP files in the webapps/your_app/ folder in Tomcat. 
You'll then be able to edit the JSP pages, save and refresh the page. See how to create webapps/your_app/ here: http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat.html